# Align Css Form to center of page (Yes, I looked at other answers, i can't get it to work)

Tags: css

I'm trying to align this html form. i've been at it for a hour and there is not hope. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I would really appreciate some help on this.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "CSS/Login.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Admin Panel </h1>
<div class = "form-div">
    <form action = "Login.php" method = "POST">
        <input type = "email" name = "emailPost" placeholder = "Enter email..." required>
        <input type = "password" name = "passwordPost" placeholder = "Enter password..." required>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
background-color: #f4f4f4;
font: normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:1.6em;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.form-div {
display: table;
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}

form {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

form input[type="email"], [type="password"] {
border:none;
background:#f4f4f4;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
outline:none;
line-height:28px;
font-size:16px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background-color:#333;
color:#fff;
padding:10px 15px;
border:none;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: align it how?  do you want the inputs and buttons stacked?

Comment: @user2796515 yes, i want it centered in the middle of the page (both horizontally and vertically centered) and the input fields and the button stacked vertically.

Comment: Hi @OmarDajani.  Is this what you had in mind: https://jsfiddle.net/eo9kcjv3/? I added percents to the heights/widths and margins.

Comment: @user2796515 - yes, that is. but i need it so that when the window is resized it will still be centered. Would using margins have an affect on this? thanks! :)

Comment: Using percentages will work when is resized.  Where px is static, a percentage will go by the screen size.  If the screen is 1000px and your `div` is 50%, the `div` would be 500px. Where using px  the size of the `div` would never change.  If this is helpful I will add as an answer.

Comment: @user2796515 thank you! yes, this can definitely be an answer :)

Comment: updated as answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using percentages will work when is resized. Where px is static, a percentage will go by the screen size. If the screen is 1000px and your div is 50%, the div would be 500px. Where using px the size of the div would never change.

See this fiddle for this example: https://jsfiddle.net/eo9kcjv3/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1> Admin Panel </h1>
  <div class = "form-div">
    <form action = "Login.php" method = "POST">
        <input type = "email" name = "emailPost" placeholder = "Enter email..." required>
        <input type = "password" name = "passwordPost" placeholder = "Enter password..." required>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #f4f4f4;
font: normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:1.6em;
text-align: center;
}

.form-div {
display: table;
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
height: 30%;
margin-top:10%
}

form {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

form input[type="email"], [type="password"] {
border:none;
background:#f4f4f4;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
outline:none;
line-height:28px;
font-size:16px;
display: block;
width:20%;
margin-left:40%;
margin-top:10px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background-color:#333;
color:#fff;
padding:10px 15px;
border:none;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}`
```